# JACKSON Json Really slow on Android?

Tags: android, json, parsing, jackson

Although on my Tablet there was no issue, running json parsing of a large file on my emulater was INCREDIBLY slow.

I read up that JACKSON JSON is a really fast processing method, so I installed it and it's WAY worse?

AM I doing something wrong, I am just using the core library, so there is litterally no overhead.

I put the data in a sqllite database.  It runs just as slow without dumping into sqlite as well so the db calls are not the issue.

Any ideas on if this is as optimized as possible?

here is the entire code:

```
public boolean dowloadfilejson(double olng,double olat, double odistance,DatabaseHelper dbc)
{   URL url;

    SQLiteDatabase db =  dbc.getWritableDatabase();
    db.setLockingEnabled(true);
    db.execSQL("delete from deals_categories;delete from deals;");      

    db.beginTransaction();

    //JsonFactory fac = Util.getJsonFactory(); // recycle JsonFactory
    JsonFactory fac = new JsonFactory(); // or just use once.
    JsonParser jp = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(URL + "lat=" + "41.778049" +"&lon="+ "-88.086898" + "&distance=10");
                jp = fac.createJsonParser(url);
                jp.nextValue();

                while (jp.nextValue() != null)
                {
                    //jp.getCurrentName();
                    if(jp.getCurrentName() =="lat")
                    {
                        Log.i("1",jp.getText());    
                    }
                    if(jp.getCurrentName() =="lon")
                    {
                        Log.i("1",jp.getText());    
                    }
                    if(jp.getCurrentName() =="distance")
                    {
                        Log.i("1",jp.getText());    
                    }
                    if(jp.getCurrentName() =="totalSize")
                    {
                        Log.i("1",jp.getText());    
                    }
                    if(jp.getCurrentName() =="items")
                    {
                        while(jp.nextValue() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) //items array
                        {String id = "";
                        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                        //Log.i("ITEM",jp.getText());   
                            while(jp.nextValue() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) //each item
                            {   //Log.i("ITEMin",jp.getText()); 
                            /*   cv.put("deal_id",c.getString("_id"));
                               cv.put("mtype",c.getString("type"));
                               cv.put("dealUrl",c.getString("dealUrl"));
                               cv.put("options_option_buyUrl",c.getString("buyUrl"));
                               cv.put("options_option_redemptionLocations_redemptionLocation_city", c.getString("city"));
                               cv.put("startAt" ,c.getString("startAt"));
                            cv.put("endAt" ,c.getString("endAt"));
                            cv.put("lat" ,c.getString("lat"));
                            cv.put("lng" ,c.getString("lng"));
                            cv.put("mediumImageUrl" ,c.getString("mediumImageUrl"));
                            cv.put("announcementTitle" ,c.getString("title"));
                              */


                              if(jp.getCurrentName() == "_id" )
                              {
                                 id = jp.getText();
                                  cv.put("deal_id",id);  
                              }
                              if(jp.getCurrentName() == "type" )
                              {
                                  cv.put("mtype",jp.getText());  
                              }
                              if(jp.getCurrentName() == "dealUrl" )
                              {
                                  cv.put("dealUrl",jp.getText());  
                              }
                              if(jp.getCurrentName() == "buyUrl" )
                              {
                                  cv.put("options_option_buyUrl",jp.getText());  
                              } 
                              if(jp.getCurrentName() == "city" )
                              {
                                  cv.put("options_option_redemptionLocations_redemptionLocation_city",jp.getText());  
                              } 

                              if(jp.getCurrentName() == "startAt" )
                              {
                                  cv.put("startAt",jp.getText());  
                              } 
                              if(jp.getCurrentName() == "endAt" )
                              {
                                  cv.put("endAt",jp.getText());  
                              } 
                              if(jp.getCurrentName() == "lat" )
                              {
                                  cv.put("lat",jp.getText());  
                              } 

                              if(jp.getCurrentName() == "lng" )
                              {
                                  cv.put("lng",jp.getText());  
                              }                                
                              if(jp.getCurrentName() == "mediumImageUrl" )
                              {
                                  cv.put("mediumImageUrl" ,jp.getText());  
                              }
                              if(jp.getCurrentName() == "title" )
                              {
                                  cv.put("announcementTitle" ,jp.getText());  
                              }



                            if(jp.getCurrentName() == "catname" )
                            {
                            String[] s = jp.getText().split("\\|");

                            for (String val : s) {

                               ContentValues cvcat = new ContentValues();
                              cvcat.put( "active" ,1);
                              cvcat.put("catname" ,val);
                            db.insertWithOnConflict ("categories", null, cvcat,  SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
                            cvcat = null;
                            ContentValues cvcatd = new ContentValues();
                            cvcatd.put("catname" ,val);
                            cvcatd.put("deal_id",id);
                            db.insertWithOnConflict ("deals_categories", null, cvcatd,  SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
                            cvcatd = null;
                                }

                            }
                            }
                            id = "";
                            db.insertWithOnConflict ("deals", null, cv, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
                            cv = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;


            } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
}
finally{
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();            
    /*  if(ih!=null)
        ihdc.close();
        ihc.close();
        ih.close();
        */
        db.setLockingEnabled(false);
        db.close();
        dbc.close();

        }

}
```

### EDIT

I found the issue for incredibly slow processing is the CONTENTVALUES.  I think I am going to scrap using that claass and write it long hand to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to use Streaming API approach there? While it can be faster, it expands code a lot, so instead of 5 lines of code you use 100. And when you use String comparisons, it may not even be faster.
So perhaps try using `ObjectMapper` and direct data-binding to POJOs?